# hide 'read more' and 'show less' tags

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't figure out why my 'read more' and 'show less' won't toggle display.

I have multiple instances of the read more tag, here is the  script that handles this:

```
<script>
(function($) {
$('.showcontent').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().next( '.cdscontainer' ).show();
     $( this).parent().next( '.showcontent').hide();
      $( this).parent().next('.hidecontent').show();

});
$('.hidecontent').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent('.cdscontainer').hide();
     $( this).parent().next('.hidecontent').hide();
      $( this).parent().next( '.showcontent').show();
});
})( jQuery );
 </script>
```

The site is www.kingkongco.com.au/c-cor/about-us  (under the staff pics)

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: Please provide relevant html and not a link to your site.

Comment: Plus your site is super-slow. Provide some code pls

Comment: Those links work fine for me on your site. Took forever to load, but it worked fine. You might look into why the site loads so slow.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, OP expects hiding of "Read more.." link, I believe.

Comment: @vp_arth ah ok gothca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `next('p')` to `next('.cdscontainer ')`

```js
$('.showcontent').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().next('p').show();
})
$('.hidecontent').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
  $('.showcontent').show();
})
```

```css
.cdscontainer {
    display: none;
  margin-top:-18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="description">As General Manager,Volker is responsible for Engineering, Professional Services and day-to-day ef cient operations of the business including manufacturing, technical…<br>
<a class="showcontent">Read more…</a></p>
<p class="cdscontainer">…and engineering services, process management<br>
and professional services delivery.<br>
Recently, Volker was with Grass Valley USA, LLC where he held a technical leadership role as Regional Operations Manager AsiaPacific.<br>
In 1993 he was a commercial and technical manager for the original Foxtel/Telstra CATV Rollout as part of Philips (Koninklijke Philips N.V.).<br>
In this role he led vendor management for over 100 OEM vendors supplying Connectivity Equipment, Active Equipment and installation materials for the Telstra HFC Cable Network infrastructure rollout.<br>
Significantly, he established service platforms for post-rollout support of the Telstra HFC Cable Network. Volker also project managed the Telstra Digital Video Network rollout program.<br>
A highly capable executive with over 28-years professional experience in radio, telecommunications, broadband and television broadcast technologies.<br>
Volker has extensive experience in system engineering, project management and delivery of professional services.<br>
Volker was awarded a Graduate Diploma of Technology Management (Deakin University) and a Bachelor of Engineering – Electrical (Swinburne University of Technology).<br>
<a class="hidecontent">…Hide Content</a></p>
```

Comment: You sir, have done me a great favour! Thank you very much Charantej Golla! 
Love how everyone else is asking for the html and css when it was clearly a JQ issue.
A fine mind you have.
(the site is slow because it's sharing a host with about 100 other sites, just to satisfy everbody's curiousity)
I've made a note of your correction, and look forward to reusing and sharing your advice in the future,
thanks again,

Comment: Welcome Khadesa. I'm happy that my answer used for you :)

Comment: Might i be so greedy and ask of your wizardry one last time?
I am now trying to style the short text by adding:


**$(".team p").css("text-align", "left");**

but it is affecting all team members, i have tried

**$(this).parent().next(".team p").css("text-align", "left");**

but alas! to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: Hold the phone!
**$(this).parent("p").css("text-align", "center");**
ought to do it,
thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

To start things off, four of your lines do nothing:

```
$( this).parent().next( '.showcontent').hide();
$( this).parent().next('.hidecontent').show();
```

and

```
$( this).parent().next('.hidecontent').hide();
$( this).parent().next( '.showcontent').show();
```

Take a look at the description of jQuery's [next function](https://api.jquery.com/next/).  In the first case, you'll be selecting the element directly after .showcontent's parent, which is .cdscontainer.  Both

```
$(this).parent().next('.showcontent')
```

and

```
$(this).parent().next('.hidecontent')
```

will be empty sets since the next element after .showcontent's parent has neither one of those classes.  Therefore, your .show() and .hide() will do nothing since there is no element to act upon.

Now, to get this to work they way that you want it to, you'll need to change the first set of bad lines to

```
$(this).hide(); //this is .showcontent
$(this).parent().next().find('.hidecontent').show(); //Need to find the .hidecontent element since it is a child of parent's next element
```

Although you can omit the second line altogether as .hidecontent is hidden/shown based upon the visibility of .cdscontainer anyway.

The second set of bad lines can then be changed to

```
$(this).hide(); //this is .hidecontent, but, as above can be omitted since .cdscontainer is hidden
$(this).parent().prev().find('.showcontent').show(); //Need to go to the parent's previous element and find child .showcontent since it appears in the DOM before .hidecontent
```

Now, that should get you where you want to be, but be careful with this sort of setup.  You're basing your functionality an awful lot on the structure of your HTML.  Should the markup ever change, and parents/children aren't the same, you could see this break.